# Lambda to turn IDictionary<string,object> values into object[]

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to create a Lambda expressions that creates an object array from an IDictionary based on given named input.

This is what I have so far:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
        { 
            {"some", "value"}, 
            {"dateTime", DateTime.Now},
            {"someNum", 52},
            {"other", "values"}
        };

string[] inputArray = { "input", "dateTime", "someNume" };

var processedArray = inputArray.Select(i => dic.Where(d => d.Key == i).Select(kvp => kvp.Value)).ToArray();
```

This doesn't work, it returns an `IEnumerable<object>` but all the members are type `KeyValuePair<string,object>` just, it appears, without the key data.

I think there are a few things wrong with this. I don't think I should be using `dic.Select()` as key entries in dictionary are unique and I am obviously referencing the value wrong or missing a way to cast each result.

I am not sure how to achieve this using a single Lambda.  I need to work out the Lambda as I plan to use it as a compiled Lambda.

Can someone advise me on how best to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
var processedArray = 
    (from key in inputArray
     where dic.ContainsKey(key)
     select dic[key]).ToArray();
```

Or using the fluent/dot syntax:

```
var processedArray = inputArray
    .Where(key => dic.ContainsKey(key))
    .Select(key => dic[key])
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to still have an element in your `processedArray` output in the case  where the dictionary misses a key (e.g. for the "input" string in your example), you could do it like this for example (using `null` for a missing entry in the dictionary):

```
var processedArray = inputArray
    .Select(key => dic.ContainsKey(key) ? dic[key] : null)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @chomba, sorry, I seem to have stepped over your suggested edit when I was still trying to improve it myself, without noticing your suggestion. I incorporated it after I noticed. Feel free to suggest other improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the edit that is very helpful for what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to select these just by accessing the dictionary indices:

```
inputArray.Select(k => dic[k]);
```

Comment: This will throw a `KeyNotFoundException` for OPs sample input.

Comment: @Alex That's true. I think your answer's behavior is probably closer to what the OP expects.